# Missing Emulators Windows Phone 7?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7-emulator

I installed both the 7.1 and 7.8 Sdk on my machine but when I make a new project in Vs 2010 Ultimate I get a project but don't have any emulators to choose from.

[image]

I am on windows 7 64bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.Close all Visual Studio and Windows Phone Emulator instances.

2.Delete the contents of %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Phone Tools\CoreCon.

3.Restart Visual Studio.

Comment: Ya that solved that problem....now every time I try to run the emulator my computer crashes.

Comment: Does your system meet the minimum requirements?

Comment: I upgrades my computer to and intel i5, 8 gigs of ram and new mother board. My last computer was able to run it.

Comment: Also try the solution in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595455/emulator-wont-show-in-visual-studio-2010