# No Emulator lists to deploy windows phone app

Tags: windows-phone

I'm not able to see any of emulator in VS 2012 express for windows phone.  My system has all requirements to run an emulator. previously I was able to debug on emulator. After uninstalling and reinstalling VS 2012 I'm unable to get emulator list and i'm getting error "There were deployment error"  and error list shows " Error 1 Exception from HRESULT: 0x89721500". Please help me to solve this problem as I'm unable to test my window phone apps on my system.

Answer (score 44):

Maybe you could fix this issue by deleting this folder:

When you use Visual Studio 2012

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Phone Tools\CoreCon\11.0
```

When you use Visual Studio 2015

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Phone Tools\CoreCon\12.0
```

Then open VS2012 or VS 2015 again.

If not repairing is always recommended

Comment: I don't have this folder on the microsoft directory. Any others suggestions ?

Comment: Worked for me too, in this case, for the VS 2013 Express for Windows. Thanks!

Comment: Worked perfectly for 2015

Comment: Worked for me with VS 2015 as well. You might have a folder that says 11.0 or 12.0, they are hidden folders so either just directly access them from explorer address bar or turn on hidden files/folders to see/delete.

Comment: Why isn't this answer accepted? Give this noble man his points for he has helped me keep my hair on my head :D

Comment: I didn't have such a folder, made a "CoreCon" research in the "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft" folder, found one, deleted it, and the issue was resolved!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Daniel's answer, you may need to then manually repair the emulator install from programs and features in control panel.