# Visual Studio 2015 missing emulators

Tags: windows-phone-8-emulator, visual-studio-2015

I have VS2015 and VS2013 installed side-by-side. In VS2013 I have a list of emulators to start my app and it works awesome.

But VS2015 only has device in the list. How do I add the phone emulators to Visual Studio 2015?

**UPDATE:**

After playing around some more I've dug up some new findings.

1. Creating a new universal JavaScript project has the same issue
2. Creating a new universal C# project **DOES** show a list of emulators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rerun the installer. Make sure that the desired options are checked (probably either Windows Phone 8.1 Emulator or Microsoft Visual Studio Emulator for Android, you don't say which emulator you are interested in). If in doubt, just check everything.

Comment: Try switching from ARM to x86 in the target drop down (to the left of the run arrow).

Comment: Also, sometimes projects don't update right from one version of visual studio to another. If creating a new project works, you can do that, then copy the contents of your old project into your new project. I find that the easiest way to do this is with beyond compare at [link](http://www.scootersoftware.com) to copy all the important information from one project to another (though for this to be fast, the new and the old project need the same name).

Comment: +1 I've installed CTP 6 and everything is working now. Not sure if it was bug or if a complete re-install that made it start working. Thanks anyways though.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me!
Although I had CoreCon\12 and vs2015.3 instead of CoreCon\11 and vs2012

> Maybe you could fix this issue by deleting this folder
>
> C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Phone Tools\CoreCon\11.0
>
> Then open VS2012 again.
>
> If not repairing is always recommended

original post : [no-emulator-lists-to-deploy-windows-phone-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18183133/no-emulator-lists-to-deploy-windows-phone-app)

Answer (score 0):

If you had unloaded your start project, it may not be your start project anymore after reloading. So do a right click -> Set as Startup Project and then hopefully the emulators will reappear.