# Running a Cordova project on WP8 in VS2015

Tags: android, cordova, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2015, windows-phone-8-emulator

I've just started a blank Cordova project on Visual Studio 2015, the intention being to use it to develop mobile apps in the future. I've been able to get it to run in the emulator on Android and even onto an iOS device (through a Mac), but I haven't been able to figure out how to run straight onto a WP8.1/Android device, or on a WP8 emulator. When I try, I get this message:

> Error running one or more of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 2
>
> You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project

The Android device also says, above that:

> ERROR: Failed to deploy to device, no devices found.

There's very little documentation online, and because it's all so new, Google hasn't been particularly enlightening. It's possible that I'm missing some software, but I don't know what.

For the devices, it could be that I'm supposed to select the device from a list somewhere, but I can't see anywhere that could be. For the emulator, I'm assuming I'm missing software, or a setting is wrong on my PC, but have no idea what it could be.

Comment: Have you enabled the [developer options](http://www.androidcentral.com/all-about-your-phones-developer-options) on your Android device?

Comment: Developer options is enabled, as is USB debugging, and yet it won't deploy to the phone. In fact, after repairing Visual Studio, it won't even compile. It gets stuck on "Generating resource IDs".

Comment: Fixed Android now- the issue was apparently the version of the Android SDK. I downgraded and it now works, both on the emulator and on a device I tried. Only thing left is the Windows Phone emulator.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue with WP8:

I had been playing around with different versions of VS... un-installing and re-installing 2013 and 2015 and eventually hit the same issue as you.

The solution here worked for me:

[No Emulator lists to deploy windows phone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18183133/no-emulator-lists-to-deploy-windows-phone-app)

I do not have an android phone to test with t the moment, so I have not seen the android device issue.

Comment: I deleted that folder and restarted, to no avail. However, I also tried repairing Visual Studio, which allowed me to run on the Windows phone directly, so that's one victory. That'll work for my use, but I'll still try to get the emulator working.